# could not resolve dependency from react-html-parser while installing react-html-parser

Tags: reactjs

could not resolve dependency peer react @14.0.0 ||15.0.0|| 16.0.0-0 from react-html-parser while installing react-html-parser

I am stuck here.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9itU.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seemes that react-html-parser lib hasn't been updated since more than 5 years (See https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser?activeTab=versions).

So the React version needed to use it is dated from 5 years ago. Aka React 14, 15 or 16.

If you are making the choice to used even when knowing this, just run

```bash
npm i react-html-parser --legacy-peer-deps
```

Or, instead you can use a much more recent lib that is compatible with the latest version of react and is updated almost ever week:

***html-react-parser***: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser